# How to difference sockaddr_in struct from same subnetwork and different IP/users

Tags: c++, c, tcp, winsock

I am developing a gaming server using the Winsock2 API from Windows, just for now until porting it to Linux.

The main problem I have found is that I don't know how to differentiate gaming clients that come from the same router/network. Let´s imagine 2 gamers that are in the same network going to the Internet through the same router IP and port with, for example IP 220.100.100.100 and port 5000, how can my C/C++ server differentiate both TCP connections and know that they are two different gamers?

Can I find any difference in the sockaddr_in struct that returns the socket when accept(...) returns ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the two clients (gamers) are behind a router, it is hard to differentiate them just using sockets.

If you are using TCP then it shouldn't be a problem.  Each client connects over a unique socket so you know anything coming in on that socket is from them.  When they first log on, I assume they supply some credentials (name, password) so just associate the credentials with the socket.

If you are using a connectionless protocol, like UDP, the first time they contact you, you give them a unique number or token.  Next time they contact you, they must include their token in the message, so that you can identify them.

Am I missing something?

Comment: Thank you very much, this is pretty much what i am thinking to do, use TCP for loging and keepAlive and some kind of UDP based protocol for other comunications. If both sockets from the same ip and port are properly diferenciated at my server and every thing i send through them will get to the proper gamer...then I am done :D. I mean only at the TCP login and keepAlive part...

Answer (score 0):

Couldnt you differentiate by testing the socket descriptor that the call to socket(); returns?